Recent movie about a bookish ex-prodigy girl learning to socialise again
I watched the trailer for this movie on IMDb either in 2017 or 2016.
It's the story of a teenage girl who used to be a child prodigy, went to college when she was really young but something happened and she is now sort of a recluse who loves to read books.
She has a male father figure (maybe father, uncle, neighbor) that encourages her to go out and socialize with boys her age but she dismisses them as stupid etc. 
It seems to take place in a large city, maybe New York... Please help!

It sounds like the movie Carrie Pilby:

A person of high intelligence struggles to make sense of the world as it relates to morality, relationships, sex and leaving her apartment.

iTunes says:

Carrie Pilby is a 19-year old genius, a year out of Harvard, and living in New York City. Burdened with an overactive moral compass in a world she considers to be populated by oversexed, deceitful hypocrites, Carrie finds herself isolated, friendless, dateless, and unemployed. When Carrie's absentee father suggests she get a roommate or a job, and her psychiatrist makes a list of goals she is to achieve between Thanksgiving and the end of the year, Carrie resists the mundane until her goal-oriented brain forces her to embrace these tasks with a vengeance. 

